# How to add custom classes to Laravel Voyager menu items

Tags: html, css, laravel, voyager

I have *main* menu in Voyager which has some items in it (navbar buttons).
I output all of the items in my blade view with

```
{{menu('main', 'bootstrap')}}
```

Problem is that all of the items (navbar buttons) have the same look to them.
I have custom classes for them in my style.css file but I could not find a way to style all the items differently.
Database menu does not provide a menu_items table where I could add my own classes either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that you have to use `{{menu('main', '_json')}}` and afterwards you iterate each of the items in a foreach loop and do whatever you want with them.

Answer (score 0):

There are various methods to do this:

**Method 1:** If you are using the bootstrap in that case you can use the below code inside your blade template. Make sure to change the `FrontendMenu` as per the menu name that you added in the backend.

```
{{ menu('FrontendMenu', 'bootstrap') }}
```

**Method 2:** If you want to add custom style and make more changes to the menu in that case you can follow the below steps.

- Go to the path `projectname\vendor\tcg\voyager\resources\views\menu`
- Copy the default.blade.php and paste it inside `projectname\resources\views`
- And rename it as `mymenu.blade.php`
- And change the menu code in template from `{{ menu('FrontendMenu', 'bootstrap') }}` to `{{ menu('FrontendMenu', 'mymenu') }}`
- Then finally you can make any changes inside `mymenu.blade.php` that you want to do you can add class to ul, li and make changes in html as well.

**[Refrecen Video](https://voyager.devdojo.com/academy/custom-menus/)**